# I am trying to connect mysql with python and while installing the connector, I am getting this error-

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Error- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: We need to see the code that you are running. You tell us the error, but we don't know what the code is to try to help you tell what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.